# Ось z в Draggable ursina engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

Я пытаюсь сделать "эдитор" для ursina engine. Когда я начал делать стрелки scale мне понадобился класс `Draggable`, вот код который я написал:

```
class DragCube(Draggable):
    def __init__(self, scene, Color=color.green, Visible=True, Scale=(1, 0.25, 0.25),
                 Position=Vec3(0, 0, 0), Collider='box', Lock=(1, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(
        color = Color,
        visible = Visible,
        model = 'cube',
        parent = scene,
        scale = Scale,
        position = Position,
        lock = Lock
        )

class scaleRows():
    def __init__(self, scene):
        self.rows = []
        self.scene = scene

    def calculate_scale(self):
        scale = ()

        for i in rannge(3):
            position = self.entity.position[i]
            scale = self.entity.scale[i]
            scaleCenter = scale / 2
            offset = position + scaleCenter

            row = self.rows[i]
            rowPosition = row.position[i]
            scalePlus = rowPosition - offset

            scale.append(scalePlus)

        return scale

    def update(self):
        if self.rows == []:
            rowX = DragCube(self.scene, Position = self.entity.position + Vec3(1, 0, 0),
                            Lock = (0, 1, 0), Scale=(1, 0.25, 0.25))
            self.rows.append(rowX)
            rowY = DragCube(self.scene, Position = self.entity.position + Vec3(0, 1, 0),
                            Lock = (1, 0, 0), Scale=(0.25, 1, 0.25))
            self.rows.append(rowY)
            rowZ = DragCube(self.scene, Position = self.entity.position + Vec3(0, 0, 1),
                            Lock = (0, 0, 0), Scale=(0.25, 0.25, 1))
            self.rows.append(rowZ)
```

класс `scaleRows` - **скрипт**, но когда я начил делать стрелку по направлению *z*, я столкнулся с проблемой: параметр *Lock* реагирует только на первые два значения, как я понял, класс `Draggable` можно использовать только в 2d.

**Есть ли какие-то альтернативы но в 3d?**
**Возможно уже есть редакторы 3д объектов в сети?**

Буду рад вашим ответам!